# How is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion

How is [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32411/should-hindus-worship-brahmins-instead-of-white-people-according-to-scriptures) off-topic?

The question is not off-topic because it has an answer from Hindu scriptures, as the provided answer precisely shows.

Comment: Answer in Hindu scriptures is not what defines if the question is off-topic or not. The question and its topic will decide if it is on-topic or off-topic. The site's scope is not deciding who should worship whom especially when it is about caste and related topics.

Comment: " instead of white people" that's what is making it off-topic...

Answer (score -5):

This question is not off topic, but crass and vulgar.  Hindus do have white-worship (caste) but it cannot be asked in this crude manner (I have posted here how the Buddha slapped down a Brahmin's self-definition as one with white skin).

Comment: You're right that Hindus do have white worship, but not because of caste, but because of British colonialism. Hindus worship Europeans. In the Mahabharata times, black/dark skin was considered beautiful. Krishna and Draupadi had very dark skin and they were known to be beautiful. So in ancient India, skin color was not important like it is in contemporary India.

Comment: Brahmins are generally white whereas Shudras are generally black, but that is not the cause of white-worship. The cause of white-worship is British colonialism. And more importantly, Indians worship not merely people with white skin, but *Europeans/white Westerners*. Indians could care less if you're a Japanese person with white skin.